# How to make HashMap of Classes in Java

Tags: java, class, instanceof

I'm trying to make a HashMap of Classes in Java, and it gives me inconsistent errors and doesn't want to compile... Is it even possible to do this?

```java
package com.something;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class ColumnsResultSet {
    private static HashMap<String, Class<?>> columnTypes = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();

    static {
        columnTypes.put("TABLE_CAT", String); // String cannot be resolved to a variableJava(33554515)
        columnTypes.put("COLUMN_SIZE", int); // Syntax error, insert ". class" to complete ExpressionJava(1610612976)
        columnTypes.put("MAP", HashMap<String, String>); // Syntax error on token ">", Expression expected after this tokenJava(1610612967)
        columnTypes.put("ARRAY", String[]); // Syntax error, insert ". class" to complete ExpressionJava(1610612976)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, adding `.class` helped with everything except `HashMap`, thanks! I don't think it does what I need anyway though, cause the intention was to use it with `instanceof` for downcasting, but it doesn't look like I can use those classes with `instanceof`, neither could I use them for downcasting...

I mean something like:

```java
Class<?> Cls = columnTypes.get("ARRAY");
String[] test = new String[0];

(test instanceof Cls); // doesn't compile
String[] downcast = (Cls) test; // doesn't seem to work either
```

Will probably try something else then.

Comment: a well-intentioned tip: Don't *guess* and *try*, but rather *learn* how the Java syntax works. It will save you a lot of headache in the future. Your attempts don't work because this is simply not how Java works.